# Pause drawing button (plus others) missing from view window

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, tools

The pause-drawing, refresh, and data/layout toggle buttons have disappeared from my view window.  I'm using ArcGIS Desktop Standard 10.4.1. I've not upgraded recently or made any changes to the ArcMap configuration. I recognize there are other ways to accomplish these tasks, but I enjoy the convenience of these tools in the lower left corner of the map.

I'm not aware of this button configuration being a toolbar, but I did search through the toolbars unsuccessfully.

These tools are available in 10.4.1. See [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/map/working-with-arcmap/pausing-the-map-s-drawing.htm).

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can show/hide these buttons by selecting View from the menu bar then selecting/deselecting Scroll Bars:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  Apparently these buttons are part of the "Scroll Bars". The "View" menu has an option to toggle the Scroll Bars on/off. Mine were toggled off.